# Exact word match in excel using grep in perl

Tags: perl, unix

I am trying to search text in csv file using perl. But I need the exact match, lets see if I am searching a word U i dont want script to show US in the result. I have tried using "" & /b in the beginning and in end, it works if I store the values from CSV to array but if i want to search in CSv directly it is not working.
my $curr = U
if(grep $curr, "test.csv")
print "Done"

this is showing me US as output

Comment: I'm not sure about the csv side of it, but have you tried using regex? perl has some nice regex functions for searching, like `/^U$/`.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the whole code, properly, including semicolons etc.

Comment: no issues with semicolon etc

Comment: use FileHandle;
use warnings;

use lib '/home/a525457';


if(grep "U", "test.csv")
{
   print "Create filter for $curr";

}
else
{
print "Node $curr is not in AC File";
}

Comment: `grep` does not grep the content of a file, like the *nix command. It greps an argument list, e.g. `grep /U/, @array`.

Comment: so u mean i will have to store everthing from CSV to array first, my @nodes;
$curr = J;                             //Don’t assign value to $curr here
open(my $FileHandle, '<', $filename ) or die $!;
chomp($curr);
chomp($filename);
while (my $line = <$FileHandle>)
{
  next if $line =~ m/^#/; # Look at each line and if if isn't a comment
  push (@nodes, $line);   # we will add it to the array.
}
 
if (grep /\b$curr\b/, @nodes)
{
   print "Create filter for $curr";
 
}
else
{
print "Node $curr is not in AC File";
}
close $FileHandle;
~
Is there any other short menthod

Comment: @Richa Don't post code in comments, use the edit button to add it to your question.

Answer (score 4):

First off, let me correct you on a misunderstanding. This:

```
grep "U", "test.csv"
```

...does not `grep` the file `test.csv` for the string `U`, it greps the list of strings `test.csv` for items where `"U"` evaluates to true (which is all of them, `"U"` is always true). In Perl, `grep` is applied to a list of arguments, like so:

```
grep /foo/, @list;
```

However, you do not need `grep` for this. Using it would mean reading the whole file into memory to create an argument list for `grep`, and generally speaking there is no benefit to doing that, and mostly just added cost.

I assume what you are looking for here is a simple way to check for an exact string in a csv file. A simple way to do that is to use negative lookaround assertions:

```
my $del = ",";     # your csv delimiter
my $search = "U";  # the text you search for

while (<>) {
    print if /(?<![^$del])$search(?![^$del])/;
}
```

The `(?<![^$del])` asserts that the character before your string is not a non-delimiter character, and likewise `(?![^$del])` asserts that the character after is not a non-delimiter character. The double negations may seem complicated to keep track of, but the benefit is that they also match the conditions where the search string is not surrounded by delimiters on either side, i.e. beginning or end of the csv line.

The diamond operator here will open files given as arguments to the script and read through their content for each iteration of the while loop. E.g.:

```
perl mygrep.pl test.csv
```

This is not a complete solution, but it should give you an idea how to get where you are going.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print if(/\bU\b/)'' your_csv_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
info   info US   info    cat
info   info U   info    cow
info   info    info    dog
info   info U   info    dinosaur 
info   info    info    bat
phoenix.209> perl -lne 'print if(/\bU\b/)' temp
info   info U   info    cow
info   info U   info    dinosaur
```

or you could also use grep on command line as below

```
> grep -w U temp
info   info U   info    cow
info   info U   info    dinosaur
```

Comment: This will also match strings such as `"This is not an U"` and `"U-boot"`.

Comment: yeah sarathi, I want only U, thats what i asked actually, i need only exact match